# Word count of a row in excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, row, cell

I have an excel file with multiple columns. In one column I have different comments. I want to create a column just beside it to find the number of words in the comment columns using python code. Is there any possibility.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import xlrd
import os
from string import punctuation, translate
from collections import Counter

filename = u'test.xlsx'
sheet_no = 1  # To get the first sheet of the workbook
path = 'C:\Users\myUsername\Directory for Excel files'
punctuation_map = dict((ord(c), u' ') for c in punctuation)

for filename in os.listdir(path):
   if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
      print filename
      workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
      sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(sheet_no)
      values = []
      for row in range(sheet.nrows):
          for col in range(sheet.ncols):
              c = sheet.cell(row, col)
              if c.ctype == xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT:
                 cv = unicode(c.value)
                 wordlist = cv.translate(punctuation_map).split()
                 values.extend(wordlist)
                 numberWords = Counter(wordlist)
                 print sum(numberWords.values()), ' words for that column'

      count = Counter(values)
      print sum(count.values()), ' total words counted (from all columns)'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df #is your dataframe

counter = [] #future column you want

for string in df.Comments.values: #for each string in your "Comments"
    counter.append(string.count(' ') + 1) #num of spaces + 1

df['num_words'] = counter #add the column
df = df[['num_words', 'Comments']] #change the order of columns
```

my df was
[my df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qUom.png)

and I finally got [this df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er9Bf.png)